# Joomla template not recognised

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm making an Joomla 2.5.8 template, but joomla wont recognice it.

I have this file structure (note, it's an subdomain)

```
kadobos (root of subdomain)
    |>templates
          |>kadobosTemplate
                |>index.php
                |>templateDetails.xml
```

The index.php is now only holding the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>KadoBos, voor al uw speelgoed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welkom op deze website
    </body>
</html>
```

And the templateDetails.xml holds this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<install version="1.5" type="template">
    <name>kadoBosTemplate</name>
    <author>Marc Meesters</author>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>
        Template op maat gemaakt voor KadoBos, door Marc Meesters
    </description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    </files>
</install>
```

But i don't see the template at the template manager. So i can't select it for the website as default template. How can i let joomla recognice it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you're using Joomla 2.5, your XML file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="template" client="site">
    <name>kadoBosTemplate</name>
    <author>Marc Meesters</author>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>
        Template op maat gemaakt voor KadoBos, door Marc Meesters
    </description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

Note that `<install>` should be `<extension>` and `1.5` should be `2.5`.
I've also added  `client="site"` which will specifically tell Joomla that the template is for the frontend.

Be sure to reinstall the template after making these changes.

Comment: reinstall??? How am i supposed to do that? sorry for that simple question, but i'm verry new to this kinde of programming

Comment: when making a template or extension, you don't simply create a folder. It's has to be installed so that it registers in the database. Make a zip of the **kadobosTemplate** folder, and in the Joomla backend, go to Extensions >> Extension Manager, browse for the zip file and click "Install". You should read the Joomla Documentation a little to give you an idea of how Joomla works.

Comment: Done. had to add an question mark at the end of the first line, and then it worked. If you can add that question mark to your answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your help and patience

Comment: Instead of re-installing it, if it's already in the right location on the server you can use the 2.5 "Discover" feature `Extensions->Extension Manager->Discover->Discover button` to find templates, modules or anything else that might be in Joomla! directory.